# Inserting javascript array into HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, dropdown

I'm completly new to js, I know a bit of Python but I get confused combining JS with HTML.

I'm trying convert an array into a HTML dropdown list but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Exercise Arrays</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <script>
        var city;
        var userInput = [];
        while (city !== "stop") {
            city = prompt('Please enter a city or type: "stop" to end');
            if (city === "stop") {
                break;
            }
            else {
                userInput.push(city)
            }
        }
        document.write("<h1>Exercise arrays </h1>")
        document.write("<h2> States: </h2>")
        document.write("<form><select>" + city + "</select></form>")
    </script>

    </table>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: In general, don't use `document.write`

Comment: You have the same break condition twice. You can change the while loop to `while (true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop your list and add [`option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) elements to your dropdown. I restructured the static parts to just HTML and access the `select` via its `id` here:

```js
var city;
var userInput = [];
while (true) {
    city = prompt('Please enter a city or type: "stop" to end');
    if (city === "stop") {
        break;
    }
    else {
        userInput.push(city)
    }
}

// For each item referred to as `city`, add an option
userInput.forEach(city => dropdown.add(new Option(city)));
```

```html
<h1>Exercise arrays</h1>
<h2> States: </h2>
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you! I should take a few steps back and learn more basics.

Comment: Basics are definitely valuable. If this answered the question you can mark it as such by clicking the checkmark outline on the left.